# .Take(5) returns a count of 0 on an ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, take

I'm trying to use LINQ to return the top 5 ping results from an `ObservableCollection<PingReply>` but the resulting `IEnumerable` has a count of 0.

Can anyone explain why the `lastFive` object in the code below returns a count of 0 when `.Take(5)` is applied to `PingReplies`?

When a ping is sent, the `PingReplies` collection get's that object in the `ObservableCollection`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace XXX.ServerMonitor.Servers
{
    class WindowsServer : IServer
    {
        public WindowsServer(string address)
        {
            this.Address = address;
            PingReplies = new ObservableCollection<PingReply>();
            PingReplies.CollectionChanged += new System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(PingReplies_CollectionChanged);
        }

        void PingReplies_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Action == System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
            {
                IEnumerable<PingReply> lastFive = PingReplies.Take(5);
                if (lastFive.Where(a => a.Status != IPStatus.Success).Count() == 5)
                {
                    // 5 failed attempts
                    // Server may be down
                    Console.WriteLine(Address + " may be down");
                }
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<PingReply> PingReplies { get; set; }

        PingReply IServer.Ping()
        {
            PingReply reply = Utils.Ping.Send(this.Address);
            PingReplies.Add(reply);
            return reply;
        }

        public string Address { get; set; }
    }
}
```

### [image]

Edit: Actual code uploaded

Comment: You might check the logic: you `Take` the *first* 5 and then count if there are 5 *or more* errors.

Comment: Yes, good spot (kind of) - this isn't the full logic. The full logic would be to take the final 5 from the list using `.Skip(PingReplies.Count - 5).Take(5)`. The `>= 5` is an artefact as currently `.Take()` returns a collection with 0 objects enumerated. `lastFive = PingReplies`

Comment: Then please show _actual_ code that is in question, not some pseudo-incorrect piece that has to be excused when people poke holes in it.

Comment: JD, either Copy/Paste actual, compiling, code. Best if you can reproduce it in a small complete program. If the code is 'pseudo' then say so and use more `...` (Voted to close)

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. I have uploaded further code which is the entire class. As you can see, it is not much different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is no data in the collection, `Take` returns no items. If there is actually some data around, you must have made some mistake in code you aren't showing us. Remember: select ain't broken ...

by the way, there is also a `Reverse`, instead of `Skip(Count - x).Take(x)`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip wrt Reverse - that will be useful! There is data in the PingReplies collection when I step through with the debugger, however the Source is null and Count property is 0 on the `lastFive` variable. I have added a screenshot to the original question

Comment: These `count` and `source` members you see aren't properties, they are fields. Don't care about them, it's internals of the `TakeIterator`. To see what's in there, write the following into the immediate window: `lastFive.ToArray()`

Comment: Thanks - that shows what is there. I was getting confused by the fields not showing what was expected.